# Compare string if there's at most one wrong character in Lua

Tags: string, lua, split, lua-patterns

I have a word and I want to check if it's equal to another word. If it's so then all is right, but it can be right also if there's one (and only one) wrong character.

```
local word = "table"
local word2 = "toble"
if word == word2 then
  print("Ok")
end
```

How can I split `word2`?

Comment: You want your condition to pass if the word is less than or equal to one character off from the base word? Have you heard of [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? This sounds like something you'd be interested in.

Comment: No, I haven't but it seems really interesting, thank you :)

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the string's length first, if they are equal then compare from the first character, if there's one character that is different, then the rest must be the same for your condition to be true:

```
function my_compare(w1, w2)
    if w1:len() ~= w2:len() then
        return false
    end
    for i = 1, w1:len() do
        if w1:sub(i, i) ~= w2:sub(i, i) then
            return w1:sub(i + 1) == w2:sub(i + 1)
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

Comment: The `-1` as the second arguments to `string.sub` are redundant, as they are already assumed to be `-1` if omitted.

Comment: @RyanStein Right, fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't understand how I know if there's only one wrong character, because if there's only one wrong character i can accept the comparison, but if there are two or more wrong character I can't

Comment: This does not look right it returns true even if only the first character is correct. try print(my_compare('table','t02le'))

Comment: @JaneT I put the `return true` line in the wrong place, and you are the first one to spot it. It should work fine now.